# How to relaunch an Air-based iOS application from the very first page?

Tags: iphone, ios, air

My application is an Air-based iPhone app. It opens with the last page I visited before clicking the Home button, each time I relaunch the app, while I need to open with the splash screen onward. How can I resolve this issue?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press the Home button, you don't terminate a running app. I'm sure that many of us developers have stuck with this mental model of how iOS used to work without multitasking.

So, the splash screen, or rather, the default image (Default.png) should really appear once (when your application launches). Some times, the default image appears when coming out from the background state, but this happens only if your app takes too long to show its UI. In fact, on fast iPhones, the default image disappears almost instantly even on launch (for well-written apps, that is).

I should also note that Apple actively discourages the use of the default image for splash screens. These should only be used for creating an illusion of transition, from a "launching state" (which the default image is supposed to portray), to the running state.

However, if you really have to show a splash screen every time, you should implement such a mechanism in code. `applicationDidBecomeActive:` is a good place to start, if you are writing code in Objective-C.

I don't know the event model in Air, so I can't really give you any hints for that.

Comment: Thank you Nick for the beautiful explanation. But as I need the solution for Air IOS based app,I cannot accept your answer,at least I would like to try for sometimes. Thanks and +1.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer, though old, does not answer the question. Sure, Apple gives guidelines regarding splash screen and all, but the poster asks how to prevent the app from resuming from it's previous position. If you want the app to terminate when put in the background you need to look into the [UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f7e64a7f12cd2dd1867-8000.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac1dc3127e12e25ae562d-8000) option. There's also an [Adobe blog post](http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/05/04/air-ios-background-behavior/) explaining a bit more about different background behaviors.